# How to create list view with edittext

Tags: android

I am having a list view with an edit text.I want to edit the values of each edit text and need to set it to the particular view itself.Right now the value is changing on selecting the next edit text.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh the Listview by calling

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After every edit and set the text to the Edittext accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting You Exactly.., see this example hope this will help you..
you need to use holder .

[Example](http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2014/08/edittext-in-listview-android-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple
Lets assume you have ArrayOfStrings that represent your data inside the adapter.
String [] items = new String [15];

and you have EditText etPrimaryValue;

You need to create:

public class ListEditText extends EditText{

```
public int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public void setPos(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}

int pos = -1;

public ListEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void addCutomTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher,int pos) {
    setPos(pos);
    super.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
}

@Override
public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
    super.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
}
```

}

then go back to adapter and insert this code to your editText.
etPrimaryValue.addCutomTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(position == holder.etPrimaryValue.getPos()) {
                requiredFieldsModel.get(position).setValue(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    },position);
```

This code perfectly update your model for any change to the editTexts in your list and you wont have duplicates strings.